# Выход из масива | Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void random1(int* nPtr, int n) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UKR");

    cout << "Вивiд першого масиву: " << endl << endl;

    for (int i(0); i < n; i++) {

        *(nPtr + i) = rand() % 9 + 1;

        cout << *(nPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

}

void random2(int* mPtr, int m) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UKR");

    cout << "Вивiд другого масиву: " << endl << endl;

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) {

        *(mPtr + i) = rand() % 10 + 1;

        cout << *(mPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

}

void Desiigner(int* mPtr, int* nPtr, int* xPtr, int x, int m, int n, int* aPtr) {

    int k = 0;

    for (int i(0); i < n; i++, k++) {

        *(aPtr + i) = *(nPtr+i);

    }

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) {

        *(aPtr + k + i) = *(mPtr + i);

    }

    cout << "Вивiд нового масиву, який включає в собi перший i другий: " << endl << endl;

    for (int i(0); i < m + n; i++) {

        cout << *(aPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    // Тепер починаю заповнення в основний масив, зі значенням х

    int kof = 0;

    int coc = 0;

    for (int i(0); i < m + n; i++) {

        for (int j(0); j < m + n; j++) {

            if (*(aPtr + i) == *(aPtr + j)) {

                kof++;

            }



        }

        if (kof >= x) {

            break;

        }

        if (kof < 2) {

            *(xPtr + coc) = *(aPtr + i);

            coc++;

        }

        kof = 0;

    }

    for (int i(0); i < x; i++) {

        cout << *(xPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

}

int main() {

    srand(time(0));

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UKR");

    int m, n, x;


    cout << "Введiть кiлькiсть елементiв першого масиву: ";

    cin >> m;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Введiть кiлькiсть елементiв другого масиву: ";

    cin >> n;

    cout << endl << endl;

    x = (m > n) ? n : m;

    int* mPtr = new int[m];


    int* nPtr = new int[n];

    int* xPtr = new int[x];

    int* aPtr = new int[m + n];

    random1(nPtr, n);

    random2(mPtr, m);

    Desiigner(mPtr, nPtr, xPtr, x, m, n, aPtr);

    delete[] xPtr;

    delete[] mPtr;

    delete[] nPtr;

    delete[] aPtr;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Привет. Такая проблема, что после строчки int coc=0;
Цикл с вложенным, там xPtr выходит за рамки, не понимаю почему, можете помочь пожалуйста решить проблему, чтобы ошибка не появлялась. Рекомендую попробовать пару раз запустить, иногда работает нормально, а иногда ошибку выдает.
Если точнее, то пишет Out of memory.

Comment: Было бы неплохо описать, что делает программа

Comment: Пока что могу сказать только что в программе не гарантируется, что coc будет меньше x, то есть, если, например, массивы будут [1,2,3,4,5] и [6,7,8,9,10], то в какой-то момент coc станет равным 6, хотя xPtr будет выделен только на 5 элементов -> получаем вылет. Работает через раз потому что это зависит от сгенерированных массивов, а они у вас генерятся рандомайзером

Comment: Решил уже, оказалось что когда уже выходит из предела, нужно было брейк делать. Спасибо.

Comment: Вообще, использование break - плохая привычка. Можно нарваться на ошибки, которые потом будет непросто найти, да и структурно алгоритм хуже выглядит

Comment: Хотел бы попросить, можете описать другими словами это:

Comment: в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A, которые не
включаются в массив B, без повторений.

Comment: Это какая-то выдержка из задания?

Comment: Просто в конкретно этой выдержке формулировка вполне хорошая

Comment: @LanceT, у вас массивах все числа положительные, не так ли?